# Error when adding alias to .profile in mac

Tags: bash, terminal, alias, .profile

I have edited my .profile file on Mac, in order to create an alias in Terminal. I have added:

`alias goto_test="cd /Library/WebServer/Documents"`

I save .profile file and run:

`source .profile`

However, Terminal returns an error:

`-bash: alias: /Library/WebServer/Documents: not found`

What am I doing wrong?

.

**Notes**

When I execute `cd /Library/WebServer/Documents` in Terminal, the path works fine.

I have noticed that defining an alias with `alias show_test="ls"` throws an error because it seems to be trying to execute "ls" with quotation marks.

`alias show_test=ls` without quotation marks does work.

But, using `alias goto_test=cd ~/` without quotation marks does not work because it is a multi-word command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disable smart quotes in OS X. Your ASCII double quotes are being replaced by fancy slanted Unicode quotes that bash doesn't recognize.

Here's a reproduction of the problem:

```
$ cat profile                                                                
alias goto_test=“cd /Library/WebServer/Documents”                            

$ source profile                                                             
bash: alias: /Library/WebServer/Documents”: not found                        

$ shellcheck profile                                                         
In profile line 1:                                                           
alias goto_test=“cd /Library/WebServer/Documents”                            
                ^-- SC1015: This is a unicode double quote. 
                            Delete and retype it.

$ cat -vE profile                                                            
alias goto_test=M-bM-^@M-^\cd /Library/WebServer/DocumentsM-bM-^@M-^]$
```

Comment: Good catch (if this is the issue). Don't use TextEdit to edit your Unix scripts, etc. Use a development editor like vim, pico, or gmacs. All three come standard on the Mac. Or, download something like [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/) .

Comment: Thanks, this worked.
I would like to add one more thing:
This solution occurred to me earlier and I tried doing the edit in Sublime Text. 
However, I was pasting code from TextEdit, and the unicode quotes must have transferred with the paste. (I didn't think this was possible.)
Be sure to do all your typing in a development editor. Pasting will not work.